# Android: OnTouchListener doesn't work

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

In my app I have a fragment which has a google map in it. When user swipes right on that fragment, I want to remove it from the Activity. Following is my code for fragment:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

public GoogleMap map = null;

public static MapFragment newInstance() {
    MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
    return mapFragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById( R.id.view_map )).getMap();

    map.setOnMapClickListener(null);
    map.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);

    view.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeListener(getActivity()) {
        @Override
        public void onSwipeRight() {
    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, +view.getWidth(), 0, 0);
            animation.setDuration(500);
            view.startAnimation(animation);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
    // do nothing   
        }
    });

    return view;
} 
}
```

Following is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dip"
android:background="@color/header_black"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="5dip">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/view_map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dip" />
```

Currently If I swipe right on fragment it doesn't do anything. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What's in your "OnSwipeListener" code?

Take a look at the [SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) in Android.  It supports fling motions which I think are the same as your swipe motions.

Try this to get the view size:

```
@Override
 protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld){
     super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);

     viewWidth = xNew;
     viewHeight = yNew;
}
```

Comment: this is the code for OnSwipeListener http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures

Comment: I suspect you're getting the view size before it's set up, in other words I suspect it's 0.  I get the view size differently, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: No I am getting correct view size. If I use the same code without map. It works fine. I think some how map is absorbing the listener.